# Ambari cluster restart error: Timeline Service V2.0 Reader not restarting

Tags: hive, ambari

Attempting to restart an Ambari-managed cluster and getting errors related to the Timeline Service V2.0 Reader service starting:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/YARN/package/scripts/timelinereader.py", line 108, in <module>
    ApplicationTimelineReader().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 353, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/YARN/package/scripts/timelinereader.py", line 51, in start
    hbase(action='start')
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/YARN/package/scripts/hbase_service.py", line 80, in hbase
    createTables()
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/YARN/package/scripts/hbase_service.py", line 147, in createTables
    logoutput=True)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/base.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 160, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 124, in run_action
    provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/providers/system.py", line 263, in action_run
    returns=self.resource.returns)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 72, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 102, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep, timeout_kill_strategy=timeout_kill_strategy, returns=returns)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 150, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 308, in _call
    raise ExecuteTimeoutException(err_msg)
resource_management.core.exceptions.ExecuteTimeoutException: Execution of 'ambari-sudo.sh su yarn-ats -l -s /bin/bash -c 'export  PATH='"'"'/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/lib/ambari-server/*:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/root/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/opt/maven/bin:/var/lib/ambari-agent'"'"' ; sleep 10;export HBASE_CLASSPATH_PREFIX=/usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop-yarn/timelineservice/*; /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hbase/bin/hbase --config /usr/hdp/3.0.0.0-1634/hadoop/conf/embedded-yarn-ats-hbase org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.timelineservice.storage.TimelineSchemaCreator -Dhbase.client.retries.number=35 -create -s'' was killed due timeout after 300 seconds
```

I have not changed any configs or installed anything new between the restart attempt; simply stopped the cluster services and attempted to restart them. Not sure what this error message means. Any debugging tips or fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution on another community [post](http://community.hortonworks.com/answers/210450/view.html).

> navigate to the host where Timeline Reader is installed and Install Hbase Client in that host

Here is how I installed HBase Client from via the Ambari UI...

1. In the Ambari UI, go to Hosts then click the host you want to install the hbase client component on
2. In the list on components, you will have option to add more, see...

[image]

3. From here I installed the HBase client
4. Then stopped and restarted the cluster via Ambari UI (got notification of stale configs (though not sure if this was my problem all along or if installing the HBase Client reaised the stale configs alert))